# Accesing localhost via IP from another computer Ubuntu

Tags: networking, xampp, localhost

I'm running localhost server using xampp on Ubuntu. I'm successfully connecting with host using its Ip address from other devices. Problem is starting to appear when i'm trying to access wordpress. Everytime i type IP/wordpress it redirecting me to localhost/wordpress so obviously it's starting to point itself instead of host.

I have 2 exact same installation of wordpress. One on windows10 and second on ubuntu. From ubuntu i can connect to windows but not the reverse. What can cause this problem?

Comment: the Wordpress config.  You need to adjust the Wordpress configuration to use an actual IP address instead of 'localhost' for its URL(s).  Even if the IP address is of the system itself.  `localhost` is a special name in all OSes that points to *itself*, so you can't use `localhost` when working with a Wordpress site configuration properly.

Comment: You are right. I changed the config and it works but only partial. It translates localhost to IP address on host computer, and  iOS device. But problem still appear on windows/android.

Comment: After configuring wordpress config in the right way the error still appears. It makes me think that could be multi-platfrom problem. I disabled firewall on host and now i can access it from another computer. Chrome browser still translating IP into localhost but when i've tried e.g. Explorer  it works.

Comment: That sounds like caching at the browser, did you erase your browser caches after making changes?

Comment: @ThomasWard you are genius. That was exactly it! After clearing cache or going into private mode page starts to finally display! Thank you very much!!

Comment: Glad to hear that solved it.  I've written a basic summary of the comments here into an answer so you can accept the answer and mark the question as solved/resolved.  In the mean time, welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary reason this happens is your Wordpress configuration.

You need to configure your wordpress site to **not** use `localhost` in its URLs.  This is a *special* name that all OSes recognize as meaning "Myself" (i.e. the system itself that you're using, rather than a remote location).  Change the Wordpress configuration to be IP based, and the URLs at Wordpress will be reconstructed to use that IP address instead of `localhost` in the URLs.

Clear your browser caches as well, and it should start using the IP address and not the `localhost` domain/URL name.